# "sudo apt-get update" command giving error in my ubuntu box

Tags: 12.04, apt

Whenever I am running "sudo apt-get update" command on my Ubuntu 12.04 box, I am getting this error:

```
Fetched 837 B in 0s (29.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring 'build' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it is not a regular file
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://installsvc.vip precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1468001658

W: Failed to fetch http://installsvc.vip/mirrors/apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/precise/Release

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am not sure what is the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: First 12.04 is beyond end of life and no longer supported.  Install a supported release. Second that is a 3rd party repo contact the maintainers but I am guessing you are using old unsupported apps there too

Answer (score 1):

You have an expired repos in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder or the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file itself.

Open your favourite console, I like `yakuake` or `konsole` (default is `gnome-terminal` I think), and do

```
sudo grep "installsvc" -R /etc/apt/
```

That will tell you where "installsvc" is referenced. In that file you want to instead link direct to the Puppet Labs repos. Delete `installsvc.vip/mirrors/` part from the repos URL (eg `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/$fileToChangeName` and manually edit the file, remember to save it before closing the program).

You also appear to have a wrongly placed file, that's not doing any harm but is being "noticed" in the `apt-get` output.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/build
```

would delete it (with no undelete), but you probably want to check it first to see if you want to keep it, `mv` and `chown` will probably be needed then.

You should also be aware that 12.04 Precise Pangolin is well out of date. Newer Ubuntus will use `apt` instead of `apt-get` but once you've fixed the issues you can:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to do the latest available upgrades including any from the newly added Puppet Labs repos (the former repos was a mirror).